# MySQL date_add() doesn't work in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try to run the following query:

```
... WHERE `date` = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR)
```

It doesn't work, so I have to use the `$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+10 hours'))`

But why `date_add` doesn't work?

Thanks much

Comment: Do you get an SQL error or does it just not return the value you anticipated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function returns a time part in addition to the date. This is not the same as using php's `date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+10 hours'))`, which only returns the date part.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR);
+-----------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR) |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2010-11-05 01:59:51               |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You could use `WHERE date = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR))` instead:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR));
+-----------------------------------------+
| DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR)) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2010-11-05                              |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int, date datetime);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, '2010-11-04');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (2, '2010-11-05');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (3, '2010-11-06');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (4, '2010-11-07');

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR));
+------+---------------------+
| id   | date                |
+------+---------------------+
|    2 | 2010-11-05 00:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

`NOW()` is a timestamp, not a date.

Example:

```
mysql> select now(), current_date();
+---------------------+----------------+
| now()               | current_Date() |
+---------------------+----------------+
| 2010-11-04 12:00:01 | 2010-11-04     |
+---------------------+----------------+
```

I think this is what you want:

```
... WHERE date = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR)
```

Comment: I don't think `CURRENT_DATE()` will work for the OP in there. The `DATE_ADD()` function still returns a timestamp with the time part.

Comment: You're right. I glossed over the PHP part of the question, but now that I read it again I think your answer is the correct approach. The OP wants "what day is it 10 hours from now?", not "10:00 today"

Answer (score 1):

You compare DateTime (result of `DATE_ADD`) with DATE. You need `WHERE date = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR))`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
WHERE date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR)
```

...does work (assuming `date` is DATETIME`), but it includes the time portion when the statement was executed -- the`date` values need to match that *exactly* to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered already but there is a better solution in this usecase:

`DATE_ADD(TODAY(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR)`

This removes one additional operation because `TODAY` returns date without time part.